# can we take auto-incremented value in parent table as a foreign key in child table?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I want to take a column in my parent table which is a primary key as a foreign key in another table. Is this a correct way to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, parent's primary key can be child table's foreign key.

This is to make sure parent table is having record first before inserting into child table.

Comment: can the value be auto-incremented?

Comment: if you are talking about primary key, yes, it can be auto increment running number.